# Undeclared signal "NF_NO_MATCH_FOUND" error in openflow 1.0

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am facing the below error when I to run a scenario similar to `Scenario_small.ned` with **UDP** packets.

`<!> Undeclared signal "NF_NO_MATCH_FOUND" emitted (@signal missing from NED file?) -- in module (Open_Flow_Processing)`

This is observed as soon as the packets from the clients reach the `open_flow_processing` module and **queue size is one**.
I am running omnet 5.1 with inet 3.6 aand openflow 1.0.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you write up a minimal working example that includes some code for us so we can see how you're trying to implement that? :)

Comment: I am implementing the following ned file:
https://github.com/danhld/openflow/blob/master/scenarios/Scenario_Small.ned 

with udp packets. I have not made any changes to the open_flow_processing.ned files. 
So for the first iteration, the address is not there at the switch, hence it emits a NF_NO_MATCH_FOUND as expected. But this signal is not being captured by the ofa_switch module which has the implementation for this scenario.